# Navigating list with keyboard events

Tags: angular

What is the best approach to navigating a links list in angular 6?

Arrows keys (up and down) will navigating the list and Enter will toggle or will navigating to a new view.

My html looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of navItems">
 <a (click)="toggleItem(item)">
 <span>{{item.name}}</span></a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using the CDK here. It provides some tooling to implement a11y things like keyboard navigation.

Comment: Any example, even simple, will be appreciated

Comment: I implemented this example:
https://codeburst.io/angular-cdk-getting-started-accessibility-a11y-1b6143b961c

when navigating the list by keyboard the item gets the focus event with chrome lightblue frame but i want it to be like a:hover...in my css.
hover and keboard navigation should be the same.

Comment: You can take a look at how those CDK a11y tools are used in Angular Material as a reference.

Comment: You can try with this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tarwq as a reference and modify the code based on your requirements.